# SpreadsheetGear - Create a workbookview by code

Tags: spreadsheetgear

How do I create a workbookview using Spreadsheetgear with code. I do not want to use the workbookview control on the form, I want to create it dynamically, then place it on a tab control all by code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a workbook view object and then add it to the tab page controls.

```
  SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView workbookView1 = new SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView();
  tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(workbookView1);
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked!
Very simple solution. For some reason could not find documentation example. Only workbooks and worksheets.